# Rewriting Java 1.5 to 1.4

Tags: java, types, parameterized

I need to rewrite Java 1.5 project to java 1.4 (there are some tools that can't swallow 1.5, so a rewrite is necessary).

How should I change these snippets, to compile them under 1.4? Is there a tool for that?

```
private FooList<Bar> list = new FooList<Bar>(...);

public List<Bar> function(Baz baz) {...}

public Iterator<Bar> iterator() {...}
```

EDIT:
I need to rewrite sources, .jars are irrelevant for my project. I mentioned compiling to express that the rewrite must be correct and acceptable by the compiler.

Comment: Compile with 1.5/1.6 targeting `jsr14` - http://alblue.bandlem.com/2010/10/compiling-java-generics-with-14.html if the only issue is the use of Generics

Comment: *"(there are some tools that can't swallow 1.5, so a rewrite is necessary)"* Really? Up to date ones? In 2012? Nearly eight years later?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: yes, the JML stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tool to converter tool like [Declawer](https://sites.google.com/site/glazedlists/Home/declawer) , but basically what it does is run through a directory of Java 1.5 source and output Java 1.4 equivalent source. It doesn't support all 1.5 features.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a tool which converts Java 5.0 classes to Java 1.4
http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/

But to answer your question you can try

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603828/java-5-to-java-1-4-source-code-backporting-tool

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547872/converting-java-1-5-source-into-1-1-source

Another option is to upgrade your system. Java 6 will be EOL soon and Java 1.4 is ten years old.

Comment: @Jeffrey Its a valid comment IMHO. I did the old add-an-answer-before-the-question-closes, but I should stop doing that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.4 does not support generics, so it would end like

```
public List function(Baz baz) {...}
```

Of course, when you get a object from the list, you would get an Object, so

```
Bar bar = function(null).get(0)
```

would not work (you need an explicit casting to assign an Object to Bar).

Answer (score 0):

Strip out the types in the declarations.  For any method that returns an object of those types, add a cast to the type that you stripped out.

Answer (score 0):

If you "just" need to have 1.4 binaries you can use RetroWeaver - http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/ - to convert the jars.  I've used it in a few projects targetting Java 1.4, and found it to work well.